# Can I buy bitcoin at a lower price?

Tags: exchange-rate

Let's say that I have some money (not a lot) and I want to maximize how much bitcoin I can get. Is there a way, besides waiting and technical analysis, to get cheaper bitcoins through legal means? (In other words, I want the lowest exchange rate possible.) The reason that I think this is feasible is because bitcoin was two dollars just 7 years ago, and though I don't expect this valuation, I would like to get it in the lower thousands (preferably below the 2018 bottom price) or hundreds without having the price crash. I think that, because of the above reason, caring people would have somewhat of an incentive to sell their bitcoins to an individual buyer through something like a dark pool: the price won't crash and they could sell more of their old BTC. Note: I won't sell it right away unless I bought at the top in order to maximize returns.

Note: mining bitcoin is not *currently* viable, though it is expected to be even after the impending halving because of the demand created by this halving partly from speculation.

Answer (score 2):

If there was a special place to buy bitcoin at a lower price, peoples or bots will rush it to buy all of them then resell it rendering this special not so special any more.

Still there is some places where you can find some interesting offer I guess, like https://localbitcoins.com/ which offer to buy bitcoin from people in real life and https://bisq.network/ which is a decentralized exchange, I suppose there must be some shady link like on the tor onion network too. Be careful of scam especially those offering to sell discout bitcoin from past hacked exchange.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to buy bitcoin at lower price is to buy via Over the Counter (OTC). They require large amount of purchase at discounted price. Two other ways is using your negotiation skills at either localbitcoins.com or paxful.com exchanges.